# Usemin creating ELIFECYCLE error when targeting multiple html files

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-modules

I am currently working through the course "Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools: Bootstrap 4" on Coursera and have run into an issue with NPM scripts. While creating scripts in my package.json file to minimize files and transfer them to a distribution folder, I keep receiving a ELIFECYCLE error while trying to run a usemin script on three separate html files which are in my root folder. For the life of me I can't figure out why I keep getting this error, as it is written exactly as was taught in the class. I have also tried to use usemin on these files individually, and one of the files works but the other two do not. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very inexperienced with programming and am trying to learn more by going through online courses like this one and have been stuck on this problem for over a week. I also have been unable to find any useful information on this problem through google searches.

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",


  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/",
    "imagemin": "imagemin img/* -o dist/img",
    "usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run copyfonts && npm run imagemin && npm run usemin"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.0",
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "imagemin": "^6.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "usemin": "^0.5.0",
    "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

This is the error log that I receive:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'run',
    1 verbose cli   'usemin' ]
    2 info using npm@6.5.0
    3 info using node@v10.13.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'preusemin', 'usemin', 'postusemin' ]
    5 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~preusemin: confusion@1.0.0
    6 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: confusion@1.0.0
    7 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: PATH: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\CoursEra\Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
    9 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: CWD: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\CoursEra\Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools\Bootstrap4\conFusion
    10 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
    10 silly lifecycle   'usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html' ]
    11 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~usemin: Failed to exec usemin script
    13 verbose stack Error: confusion@1.0.0 usemin: `usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
    14 verbose pkgid confusion@1.0.0
    15 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\CoursEra\Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools\Bootstrap4\conFusion
    16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "usemin"
    18 verbose node v10.13.0
    19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error confusion@1.0.0 usemin: `usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 usemin script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: While 

`"usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html",` 

works individually in the package.json file, both

`"usemin": "usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html",` and   
`"usemin": "usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",`

cause the ELIFECYCLE error.

Comment: After scrutinizing and comparing my html files I have come to the answer on my own. Two of my html files had scripts tags formatted at the end like this.```<script src = "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>```
while one of the files had them formatted like this: `<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>`. After formatting them all with no spaces around the equal sign, all files worked when added to the usemin script as it was originally written.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same course and had similar errors. However, I was just able to fix it. I did this by reinstalling all dev dependencies and used the current versions, not the ones in the course. I did also change the usemin command (according to another source that I found here) to

"imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir=dist/img",

However, it still did not work, so I checked all my files for errors using the following tools:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html for testing the html files; http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html, for testing the .js file and https://jsonlint.com/?json=, to test the package.json file for errors.

After I did correct all the files, the command "npm run build" did finally work.

Comment: Thank you for responding. As I said, I have figured out the issue but the resources you listed will certainly be helpful to me in the future. I forgot to mention that during this process I did come upon, and install, jsonlint with npm. I think it will be helpful in the future as it gets rid of having to copy/paste from your code editor as you can just check your JSON file from your command window. I'd check it out if you haven't seen it yet. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it out.